Environment setup for React Native on MacPro Intel Chip (Late 2013)
Is it still possible to develop React Native applications on MacPro Late 2013 (aka trash Mac).
I have been having issues in the building and compiling the applications, the error is related to java versioning conflict as I run android.
Error

Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file
'/Users/john/Documents/reactnative/employee/android/settings.gradle'
(/Users/john/.gradle/caches/8.6/scripts/epxdwcaw86bse6iu3oo72ibrp).

BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'BuildScript' Unsupported class file major version 66


I have attempted to follow the instructions from the site as well as some tutorials but issue is persisting.
Here's the output from Java
java --version
openjdk 22.0.2 2024-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 22.0.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 22.0.2, mixed mode, sharing)

Mac: macOS Monterey 12.7.6
Android: 13.0("Tiramisu") 33-ext4
Xcode version is 14.2
Command Line Tools: Xcode 14.2 (14C18)
Let me know if you need more information about my environment setup.

Edit
I went ahead and installed JDK 8 to give it a go.
openjdk version "1.8.0_422"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_422-bre_2024_07_25_03_10-b00)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.422-b00, mixed mode)

Error after the change:

error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1:
./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 FAILURE:
Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong:
org.gradle.api.internal.catalog.GeneratedClassCompilationException: No
Java compiler found, please ensure you are running Gradle with a JDK

No Java compiler found, please ensure you are running Gradle with a JDK * Try:



can you write a productive comment to improve the question?

The issue was with JDK,

I had to uninstall the other JDK versions
Uninstall openjdk via brew
Installed Zulu v 17 JDK.

